Pseudoconvex domains in one complex variables
I am trying to prove that every domain in $\mathbb{C}$ with $C^2$ boundary is (Levi) pseudoconvex. For that, suppose $\Omega$ is defined as $\rho(z)<0$, where $\rho$ is $C^2$ defining function in a neighbourhood of $\overline{\Omega}$ and $\nabla \rho \neq 0$ on $\partial \Omega$. Then we call is called $\Omega$ (Levi) pseudoconvex if for every $P \in \partial\Omega$ we have :
$\sum_{j,k=1}^{n} \frac{\partial^2 \rho}{\partial z_j\partial \bar{z}_k}(P) w_j \bar{w}_k \geq 0, \ ( > 0  \ \text{for strict pseudoconvexity})$
for all $w \in \mathbb{C}^n$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial z_j}(P)w_j =0.$
When $n=1$ the fact $\nabla \rho \ne 0$ on $\partial \Omega$ implies that $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial z}(P)w =0$ is only possible when $w=0$ and in that case, $\frac{\partial^2 \rho}{\partial z \partial \bar{z}}(P) w \bar{w} = 0$ for any $P \in \partial \Omega$. Which proves $\Omega$ is pseudoconvex.
Is my argument completely correct ? Please let me know.

I don't follow your "in that case." Take the example of the disk, so $\rho(z)=|z|^2-1$. Then $\frac{\partial^2\rho}{\partial z\partial\bar z} =1$. Ah, but the point is that we can have only $w=0$. Got it.

So do you think my proof is correct ? I was wondering how to do it if we do not have $C^2$ boundary. In that case we have to use Hartog's pseudoconvexity and I am not sure that I know how to do it in one complex dimensional domains.

Pseudoconvex is the same as domain of holomorphy.

So this the point I am not sure about. Oka proved the pseudo convexity is same as being domain of holomorphy in dimension 2 or higher right ? What about in dimension 1 i.e. in $\mathbb{C}$ ? Is the same true ?
(I got the information according to this link: https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Domain_of_holomorphy#:~:text=A%20domain%20is%20a%20domain%20of%20holomorphy%20if,Levi%20problem%2C%20formulated%20by%20E.%20Levi%20in%201911.)

Yes, your proof is correct. To show that a domain with $C^2$ boundary is Levi pseudoconvex, you want to determine the positivity of the Levi form subject to the complex tangent condition. As you have correctly calculated, the fact that you only have a single term to work with in both the Levi form and the complex tangent condition makes the computation extremely (and somewhat deceptively) simple.

For your other question in the comments, pseudoconvexity is equivalent to being a domain of holomorphy for any open subset in $\mathbb{C}^n$, for any $n \geq 1$. It just appears more noteworthy in most texts that they are equivalent in dimension $2$ and higher because this is an extremely deep result in these dimensions, and requires a lot of work to prove. Dimension $1$ ends up simplifying a lot, because every open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ can be readily shown to be a domain of holomorphy, regardless of whether it has $C^2$ boundary.

This makes perfect sense. In one dimension for any domain you show it is a domain of holomorphy by constructing a function that has zeroes converging to a limit in the boundary of the domain right ?
